# How to modify .byte variable in AVR

Tags: assembly, avr

In this program, I need to have a variable called globalSum (`globalSum: .byte 0` for init). I am having trouble figuring out how to add values from `r24` to this variable. Should I just use the Z register or is there a method to add to such a variable?

Comment: AVR is a RISC load-store machine so there is no memory-destination add.  You have to load into a register, calculate, and store the result.  If you want an example, ask a C compiler (https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: What @PeterCordes said.  Read the Assembly Language Reference for your AVR part.  If the instruction isn't there, you have to do it with multiple instructions as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write :

```
globalSum: .byte 0
```

What actually happens is that you just allocated 0 bytes in program memory, and set a label (globalSum) for these 0 bytes...

If you want a variable, it goes something like this ( in native AVR assembly):

```
.DEF globalSum = r16
```

Now you can do stuff with a kind of variable called globalSum, for example set it to 0:

```
LDI globalSum, 0
```